# how to get specific string in a string on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, substring

I have this type of string in the field of my table.

```
type_no

2345-ABC-3210002478
```

and I want to select only the last 10 digits number of the string, I expect it would be:

```
type_no_id

3210002478
```

how can I do this in PostgreSQL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: last 10 digit means anything or is it numeric value?

Comment: the last 10 digits supposed to be always a numeric value

Comment: please check below query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RIGHT() for getting desired output.

```
SELECT RIGHT('2345-ABC-3210002478', 10) type_no_id
```

If using column of a table then follow the below example

```
create table test (type_no varchar(100));

insert into test values ('2345-ABC-3210002478');

SELECT RIGHT(type_no, 10) type_no_id 
FROM test
```